# Java Criteria API and operations on java.util.Date columns

Tags: java, date, criteria-api, timespan

Is there a way to convert java.util.Date column to unix time and perform operations on that instead.

I've tried

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
Root<Trip> table = cq.from(Trip.class);
table.get(Trip_.endTime).as(Long.class)
```

but it doesn't seem to work (endTime is of type java.util.Date (DATETIME in database))

OR

Is there a way to get number of seconds between two java.util.Date columns

Thanks

Comment: `dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime()` is the time difference in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, is there any wayof doing this within criteria query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by calling a native function DATEDIFF

```
Expression<Integer> diff = cb.function("DATEDIFF", Integer.class, cb.literal("SECOND"), table.get(Trip_.startTime), table.get(Trip_.endTime));
Expression<Integer> time = cb.sum(diff);
```